# Reporting Tool for GitHub

Tags: github

My team's projects are hosted on GitHub, and I'm looking for a reporting tool that can integrate with GitHub, and allow custom reports to be developed. Things that I'm interested in are PR that are open X duration, issues that have X labels, etc.

I have tried out screenful & wavefront demos, and they do not seem all that intuitive or flexible to create the report that I am looking for, or to add custom metrics. I have looked at GitHub Marketplace, but didn't see anything promising. I don't have GitHub Enterprise, so not sure what that offers, but I am definitely open to upgrade.

So, is there any reporting tool that someone can recommend?

Comment: Welcome Henry!  Do you have any price or operating system requirements?  Are you looking for a web-app or local software?  Please update your question with a few more details. Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Take a look at [Pull Panda](https://pullpanda.com/), [Gitalytics](https://gitalytics.com/) or [Valycs](https://www.valycs.com/).

Comment: Thanks @RockPaperLizard, I do not have any special OS or price considerations.  Ease of use, functionalities, and support are more of considerations.